# Read multiple text files and iterate over them

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have multiple text files containing the links for all the pages on [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/browse/english/) website.

The format of the URL I'm scraping  is like this: `*/browse/english/a/{text file's links}`

I have scraped all the links but I'm unable to iterate over them because I don't know how to open all the text file's at once.

```
a_words.txt         
b_words.txt         
.
.
z_words.txt
```

**Code:**

```py
import string
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36'
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
url = "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/browse/english/"

# This part gets all the links from page a to z and saves to corresponding text files.

for letter in letters:
    print(f"Fetching words for letter {letter.lower()}...")
    page = requests.get(f"{url}{letter}", headers={'User-Agent': headers}).content
    soup = bs(page, "html.parser").find_all("a", {"class": "dil tcbd"})
    with open(f"{letter}_words.txt", 'a', encoding='utf-8') as output:
        for a in soup[0:]:
            text_str = (a['href']).split('/')[-2]
            print(text_str, file=output)
```

Afterwards I've no idea how to get actual text from page `a` to `z`. I'm trying this code but it doesn't work.

```py
main_url = "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/browse/english/{}/{}"
with open('links.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for char in range(ord('a'), ord('z')):
        # looping through each line in links.txt
        for links in f:
            sec_url = main_url.format(chr(char), links)
            soup = bs(requests.get(sec_url, headers={'User-Agent': headers}).content, 'html.parser')
            for div in soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'base'}):
                span = div.text
                print(f"{span:<50}browse/english/{chr(char)}/{links}")
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

f = open("D:\\Test.txt",'r')
urls = f.readlines()
urls = [url.strip() for url in urls]
f.close()
headers = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36'
base_url = 'https://dictionary.cambridge.org/browse/english/'

for url in urls:
    char = url[0]
    full_url = f"{base_url}{char}/{url}"
    soup = bs(requests.get(full_url, headers={'User-Agent': headers}).content, 'html5lib')
    word_links = soup.find_all('li', class_ = 'han t-i')
    word_links = [li.a['href'] for li in word_links]
    for link in word_links:
        r = requests.get(link,headers = {'User-Agent': headers})
        soup2 = bs(r.content, 'html5lib')
        for div in soup2.find_all('span', {'class': 'base'}):
            span = div.text
            print(f"{span:<50}browse/english/{char}/{url.strip()}")
```

Output:

```
a                                                 browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a cog in a/the machine                            browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a                                                 browse/english/a/a_words.txt
A & E                                             browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a (heavy) cross to bear                           browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a (quick/brisk) trot through sth                  browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a (whole) heap of sth                             browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a bad workman blames his tools                    browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a banner year/season/month/week                   browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a baptism of/by fire                              browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a big ask                                         browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a big/great girl's blouse                         browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a bird in the hand (is worth two in the bush)     browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a bird's eye view                                 browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a bit of a lad                                    browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a bit of fluff/stuff/skirt                        browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a bit of rough                                    browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a bit on the side                                 browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a bite (to eat)                                   browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a bitter pill (to swallow)                        browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a blanket of sth                                  browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a blast from the past                             browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a blessing in disguise                            browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a blinding flash                                  browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a blitz on sth                                    browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a blot on sb's character                          browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a blot on the landscape                           browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a bolt from the blue                              browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a bolt from/out of the blue                       browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a bone of contention                              browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a boot/kick up the/your backside                  browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a bottomless pit                                  browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a breath of fresh air                             browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a brown study                                     browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a bump in the road                                browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a bunch of fives                                  browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a bundle of laughs                                browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a bundle of nerves                                browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a cappella                                        browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a change is as good as a rest                     browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a cheap shot                                      browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a chicken and egg situation                       browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a chip off the old block                          browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a chip on your shoulder                           browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a chorus of something                             browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a clean bill of health                            browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a clean slate                                     browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a close call                                      browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a close/near thing                                browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a cloud hanging over sb                           browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a cloud on the horizon                            browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a cog in a/the machine                            browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a conflict of interest                            browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a hard/tough nut to crack                         browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a conflict of interest                            browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a credit to someone/something                     browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a crock (of shit)                                 browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a cry for help                                    browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a crying shame                                    browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a cut above                                       browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a damsel in distress                              browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a dime a dozen                                    browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a dog in the manger                               browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a dog's breakfast                                 browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a dog's life                                      browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a drop in the bucket                              browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a drop in the ocean                               browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a drop too much (to drink)                        browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a drowning man will clutch at a straw             browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a fair crack of the whip                          browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a fair shake                                      browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a fate worse than death                           browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a feather in your cap                             browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a few well-chosen words                           browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a few/couple of steps                             browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a fifth/third wheel                               browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a fifty-fifty chance                              browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a fight to the finish                             browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a figment of your imagination                     browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a figure of speech                                browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a fine figure of a man/woman                      browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a fine line                                       browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a firm hand                                       browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a fish out of water                               browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a fishing expedition                              browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a flash in the pan                                browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a force to be reckoned with                       browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a fortiori                                        browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a free ride                                       browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a friend in need is a friend indeed               browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a frog in your throat                             browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a full ride                                       browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a full, good, thick, etc. head of hair            browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a game in hand                                    browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a gift from the gods                              browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a gleam in your eye                               browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a good                                            browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a good listener                                   browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a good many                                       browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a good time was had by all                        browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a good/bad turn                                   browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a green thumb                                     browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a hair's breadth                                  browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a hard/tough nut to crack                         browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a hard/tough row to hoe                           browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a means to an end                                 browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a hard/tough row to hoe                           browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a head of steam                                   browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a heart of gold                                   browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a heavy date                                      browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a heavy heart                                     browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a heavy hitter                                    browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a heck of a someone/something                     browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a heck of a sth/sb                                browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a hive of activity/industry                       browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a hole in one                                     browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a hop, skip, and a jump                           browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a household name                                  browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a hundred/thousand/million and one                browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a kick in the butt/pants                          browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a kick in the pants                               browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a kick up the arse/backside                       browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a kick/boot in the/your backside                  browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a king's ransom                                   browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a knight in shining armour                        browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a knockout blow                                   browse/english/a/a_words.txt
à la                                              browse/english/a/a_words.txt
à la carte                                        browse/english/a/a_words.txt
à la mode                                         browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a laundry list                                    browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a leap in the dark                                browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a leap of faith                                   browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a leopard can't/doesn't change its spots          browse/english/a/a_words.txt
A level                                           browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a level playing field                             browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a lick and a promise                              browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a list as long as your arm                        browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a little bird told me                             browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a load of crap, nonsense, rubbish, etc.           browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a load of crap, nonsense, trash, etc.             browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a load/weight off your mind                       browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a long face                                       browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a long way to go                                  browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a lump in your throat                             browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a magic touch                                     browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a man of action                                   browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a man's gotta do what a man's gotta do            browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a man's man                                       browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a man/woman of few words                          browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a man/woman of his/her word                       browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a man/woman of the world                          browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a matter of life and death                        browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a matter of opinion                               browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a matter of something                             browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a matter/question of time                         browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a means to an end                                 browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a meeting of minds                                browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a pretty pass                                     browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a meeting of minds                                browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a metaphor for sth                                browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a mile a minute                                   browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a mile away                                       browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a mile off                                        browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a mine of information                             browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a miserable, poor, etc. excuse for sth            browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a moment of weakness                              browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a mouth to feed                                   browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a mug's game                                      browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a mystery to me                                   browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a narrow squeak                                   browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a nasty piece of work                             browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a needle in a haystack                            browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a new broom sweeps clean                          browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a new lease of life                               browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a new lease on life                               browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a night on the town                               browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a nip (here) and a tuck (there)                   browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a nip and tuck                                    browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a nip in the air                                  browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a nod is as good as a wink                        browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a notch on the/sb's bedpost                       browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a numbers game                                    browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a pack rat                                        browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a page in/of history                              browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a pain (in the neck)                              browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a pain in the arse/backside                       browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a pain in the ass/butt                            browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a paper chase                                     browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a parting of the ways                             browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a passing resemblance                             browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a pat on the back                                 browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a pearl of great price                            browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a penny saved is a penny earned                   browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a piece of ass                                    browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a piece of cake                                   browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a piece of the action                             browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a piece of the pie                                browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a piece of work                                   browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a piece/slice of the action                       browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a piece/slice/share of the pie                    browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a pig in a poke                                   browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a place for everything and everything in its placebrowse/english/a/a_words.txt
a place in the sun                                browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a play on words                                   browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a plum in your mouth                              browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a political football                              browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a pop                                             browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a pretty pass                                     browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a pretty/fine kettle of fish                      browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a sure thing                                      browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a pretty/fine kettle of fish                      browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a priori                                          browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a problem shared is a problem halved              browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a question mark over sth                          browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a quick study                                     browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a rainy day                                       browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a rap on/over the knuckles                        browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a raw deal                                        browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a reach of the imagination                        browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a recipe for something                            browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a reign of terror                                 browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a right one                                       browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a riot of color                                   browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a riot of colour                                  browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a ripe old age                                    browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a roaring success                                 browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a rolling stone (gathers no moss)                 browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a roof over your head                             browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a rough ride                                      browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a rubber check                                    browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a rum do                                          browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a rung on/of the ladder                           browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a safe pair of hands                              browse/english/a/a_words.txt
a screeching halt                                 browse/english/a/a_words.txt
...
zookeeper                                         browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zoological                                        browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zoological garden                                 browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zoologist                                         browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zoology                                           browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zoom                                              browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zoom in                                           browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zoom in on sth                                    browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zoom in/out                                       browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zoom lens                                         browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zoom out                                          browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zoomed                                            browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zooming                                           browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zoomorphic                                        browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zoonoses                                          browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zoonosis                                          browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zoonotic                                          browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zooplankton                                       browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zorbing                                           browse/english/z/z_words.txt
Zoroastrianism                                    browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zucchini                                          browse/english/z/z_words.txt
Zulu                                              browse/english/z/z_words.txt
Zumba                                             browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zzz                                               browse/english/z/z_words.txt
Zumba                                             browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zwitterion                                        browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zydeco                                            browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zygodactyl                                        browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zygomatic                                         browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zygomaticus                                       browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zygomorphic                                       browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zygote                                            browse/english/z/z_words.txt
zzz                                               browse/english/z/z_words.txt
```

Comment: Nope sir it doesn't work. Please try [this](https://repl.it/repls/HuskyTautRuntimeerror#main.py)

Comment: I think that u tried the code that I posted first. I have tweaked it now. Check out my latest edit. BTW, pls refrain from calling me 'sir'! Cuz I am just a 9th grader!

Comment: Thankyou sir, I've tried it but i get error on line 19. See [yourself](https://repl.it/repls/CheerfulPastelListeners#main.py).

Comment: I saw ur text file (`a_words.txt`). Isn't the text file supposed to contain this: `a_words.txt \n b_words.txt \n c_words.txt ..... z_words.txt`? Change the text file to the format that u have provided in the question and it would work.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying

Comment: You have a file called `a_words.txt` in the link that u have provided. The file contains all the words. Instead, it should contain the text that you have provided in the ques, like `a_words.txt \n b_words.txt` and so on

Comment: No sir. These files `a_words.txt` `b_words.txt` ... `z_words.txt` are inside a folder and each file contains the last part of the link https://dictionary.cambridge.org/browse/english/a/ {this part}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223913/discussion-between-sushil-and-mujtaba).